# Limit or throttle running threads in C++ Linux

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency

I am using Pagmo, a C+ API for my optimization problem. Pagmo launches a new thread when a new optimization is launched, via invocation of island.evolve(). MY point is that I don't have fine-grained control here over the type of thread that's launched "under the hood" of Pagmo. I can query Pagmo threads on their status - as to whether they've completed their run. I have a machine with 28 physical cores and I'm thinking that the optimum number of my running threads would be on the order of 28. Right now, my code just dumps the whole lot of threads onto the machine and that's substantially more than the number of cores - and hence, likely very inefficient.
I'm thinking of using a std::counting_semaphore (C++ 20) and setting the counter to 28. each time I launch a thread in Pagmo, I would decrement the semaphore counter. When it hits 0, the remaining threads would block and wait in the queue until the counter was incremented.
I'm thinking I could run a loop which queried the Pagmo threads as to their statuses and increment the std::counting_semaphore's counter each time a thread went idle (meaning its task was completed). Of course, the Pagmo threads are ultimately joined. Each time the counter goes above 0, a new thread is allowed to start - so I believe.
My questions are:

1. is the the best practice as to how to limit/throttle the number of running threads using modern C++?
2. Is there a better way I haven't thought of?
3. Is there a way to query Linux in real time, as to the number of running threads?
   Thanks in advance!
   Phil

I had tried a simple loop to launch and throttle theads creation but it didn't prove to work well and threads were launched too quickly.

Comment: One question per Stackoverflow question, please?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your post could use some editing and even perhaps provide a code snippet that would help us understand the problem more. Right now I'm only going through the documentation based on a wild guess of what you are doing there.

I've quickly checked what `Pagmo` is about and I would at first advise to be careful when limiting any library that is designed for parallel computation, from outside of the library.

I will try to answer your questions:

1. I do not think that this is the best way to throttle threads created by  an external library
2. Yes, first of all I've checked the `Pagmo` API documentation and if I understand you correctly you are using an `island` class - based on what they state in their documentation the default class that inherits `island` and is constructed by the default ctor is `thread_island` (at least on non-POSIX systems - which may not be your case). However `thread_island` can be constructed via the `thread_island(bool use_pool)` [ctor](https://esa.github.io/pagmo2/docs/cpp/islands/thread_island.html) which indicates that you can specify to these `island` classes a common thread pool which they can use. And if it is done for non-POSIX systems, it is most likely done for POSIX systems as well. So if you wish to limit the number of threads I would do this via a thread pool.
3. You can limit the maximum number of threads running on linux via `/proc/sys/kernel/threads-max`, you can also instruct a Linux system to treat some processes with less importance via `niceness`

Hope it helps!

EDIT: As a foot note I will also mention that the documentation actually encourages the use of `thread_island` even on POSIX systems. See this [link here](https://esa.github.io/pagmo2/docs/cpp/islands/fork_island.html)

EDIT2: In case that you must use `fork_island` due to their mentioned issues when `thread_safety` cannot be guaranteed. Then another option would be to limit available resources via `setrlimit` see  [this link right here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) - you are interested in setting `RLIMIT_NPROC`

Comment: After a couple hours of googling, I have not been able to find out really how to use thread pools on Pagmo. There apparently is very little documentation on this. I totally agree, a theadpool is the right choice, but the lack of documentation means that it effectively can't be done iinternal to Pagmo. Pagmo's thread_island can be set to do this, but it's not clear how to use thead_island. Moreover, it's also not clear how to set the number of threads. Pagmo apparently uses Intel tbb library for threadpools. If I find out, I'll let you know. Thanks in any case! Phil

Comment: Silly me! It appears that the threads are already being limited in my code. It turns out that thread_island() is already the default UDI (user-defined island) which is invoked when you instantiate pagmo::island() and the default for pagmo::thread_island() is to use the Intel TBB (intel thread pool library) if it was installed with Pagmo (which I think I did). TBB's default is to set the number of threads in the thread pool to the number of cores and I'm imagining the number of cores if you have hyperthreading enabled would be twice the number of physical CPU cores. Thanks again for you help!

Comment: Glad I could help, as per community guidelines if you found this answer helpful please upvote it. If you believe it is the correct answer mark it as such. Thanks and good luck with your projects.